# Running an arbitrary command/program on selenium grid node

Tags: testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Is it possible to run an arbitrary OS program on the selenium node before running tests?

Why I need such a weird thing:

In one test of the web application I need to simulate mouseover for 1 second, but the thing is - if there is a mouse pointer over the browser window then selenium webdriver doesn't keep mouseover event for long time. It's getting interrupted after several milliseconds and after that the real mouse pointer starts emitting the mouseover event.

So what I'd like to try is to run a trivial program that moves mouse cursor to the screen corner to not interfere with browser window.

Any ideas?

**UPD**: created a trivial app to run before starting a particular driver that would move cursor to the corner: https://github.com/zerkms/MoveCursor

Comment: You can build this using Ant or Maven, and then have it to execute a shell command to open your program before running the actual tests.

Comment: @aimbire: to run it where? I don't know at which node it will run

Comment: How does the script point to the nodes?

Comment: @aimbire: script doesn't know anything about nodes, it knows only about selenium grid hub.